# Pandas stack with level parameter

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2, 2)), index=["A", "B"], columns=["foo", "bar"])
print(df1)

   foo  bar
A  1.0  1.0
B  1.0  1.0

print(df1.stack())
A  foo    1.0
   bar    1.0
B  foo    1.0
   bar    1.0
```

I want to stack this DataFrame such that the column is at level 0 instead of -1. However, when I pass this in the parameter, I seem to get the same result:

```
print(df1.stack(level=0))
A  foo    1.0
   bar    1.0
B  foo    1.0
   bar    1.0
```

It seems like I'm not understanding correctly how the level parameter works. Moreover, I would like to use level parameter instead of e.g. first pivoting the DataFrame, as I am dealing with MultiIndices in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `level` parameter of [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) indicates which **column** level should be stacked, not its destination in the index.

Here you have a single level for columns, so `0` and `-1` are effectively the same column level.

Consider this other example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2, 2)), index=['A', 'B'],
                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('X', "foo"),
                                                      ('X', 'bar')]))
     X     
   foo  bar
A  1.0  1.0
B  1.0  1.0

df1.stack(level=0)
     bar  foo
A X  1.0  1.0
B X  1.0  1.0

df1.stack(level=-1)
         X
A bar  1.0
  foo  1.0
B bar  1.0
  foo  1.0
```

You might be looking for [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)/[`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
df1.stack().swaplevel()
# or
df1.stack().reorder_levels([1, 0])

foo  A    1.0
bar  A    1.0
foo  B    1.0
bar  B    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Oh right, so if I understand your answer correctly, the level parameter refers to what level of the columns are stacked, rather than referring to what level the column ends up in the index. As such, to obtain the desired behavior, I should stack and then reorder. Thanks for your prompt and thorough feedback!

Comment: Exactly, you got it ;) I'll edit the answer to make this more explicit.